# Select dataframe if both values exists

Tags: r

Here is example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=1:2, account=c(-1,-1))
df2 <- data.frame(x=1:3, account=c(1,-1,1))
df3 <- data.frame(x=1, account=c(-1))
ls <- list(df1,df2,df3)
```

Failed attempt:

```
for(i in 1:length(ls)){
  d <- ls[[i]]; if(d$account %in% c(-1,1)) { dout <- d} else {next}
}
```

I also tried: (not sure why this doesn't work)

```
grepl(paste(c(-1,1), collapse="|"), as.character(df1$account))
```

gives: (which is correct, since `|` means or, so one of the values is matched)

```
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

however, I have tried this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=1:2, account=c(-1,1))
grepl(paste(c(-1,1), collapse="&"), as.character(df1$account))
```

gives:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

I would like to store only the subset of dataframes that contain both `-1,1` values in column `account` otherwise neglect.

Desired result:

```
d
  x account
1 1       1
2 2      -1
3 3       1
```

Comment: You probably don't want to name something `ls`, as that's also the name of a very important command.

Comment: @ oh yes, I just made it up for this example.

Comment: Are the `account` columns always going to have only `-1` and `1` in them?  Two of the answers below assume so

Comment: @RichardScriven, yes always. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, you could stop using a list of data.frames:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- rbindlist(ls, idcol="id")

#    id x account
# 1:  1 1      -1
# 2:  1 2      -1
# 3:  2 1       1
# 4:  2 2      -1
# 5:  2 3       1
# 6:  3 1      -1
```

And filter the single table:

```
DT[, if (uniqueN(account) > 1) .SD, by=id]
#    id x account
# 1:  2 1       1
# 2:  2 2      -1
# 3:  2 3       1
```

(This follows @akrun's answer; `uniqueN(x)` is a fast shortcut to `length(unique(x))`.)

Answer (score 1):

We could loop through the `list` and check whether the `length` of `unique` elements in 'account' is greater than 1 (assuming that there are only -1 and 1 as possible elements).  Use this logical index to filter the `list`.

```
ls[sapply(ls, function(x) length(unique(x$account))>1)]
```

Comment: actually, I tried to accept your answer since came as first, but it gave me 7min time before I could accept. Than came Frank with his "more polished" answer so had to accept his answer :)

Comment: @Maximillian It's okay.  Frank's answer would be more fast.